# How to correctly cross reference program listing in Lyx

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I learnt from another question that best way to include code was to make a child document with a program listing, which is great.

My question is how do I correctly label the program listing?

For a chapter it is `chap:Name` and for subsection it is `sub:Name`, so what is it for program listing?

Justification is when I cross reference I want the equivalent  formating like when I  reference a section `... section 2.1 ...` when referenced. (I'm not actually writing "section" that is auto generated by lyx, I want the same for listing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a 'correct' answer, as you have to define this yourself. LyX uses the `refstyle` packages for such formatted references, and this does not, as far as I can tell, have definitions for program listings.

So what you would do is I think to add such a definition to your preamble, in Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble. A simple example is

```
\newref{lst}{
   name   = listing~,
   names  = listing~,
   Name   = Listing~,
   Names  = Listings~,
   rngtxt = {~to~},
   lsttxt = { and }}
```

With this definition you should use `lst:` as a the prefix in the labels. If you want some other prefix, change the `lst` in `\newref{lst}` to the prefix of your choice.

Note however, that as long as you don't use ERTs, I think you just need `\newref{lst}{name   = listing~}`, as LyX simply doesn't have support for the other reference formats, unless I'm mistaken.

A final note: generally there is no correct way of writing labels for chapters, sections etc. either. The use of `chap`, `sec`, `eq` and so on is just a convention, it not something you need to do. *Unless* you use the `refstyle` package. This does actually need to have the right string as prefixes to figure out what type of object is referred to. The `cleveref` package is cleverer in this sense, as it figures stuff out on its own.

Comment: Oh, that is beautiful!